# jquery datepicker not working on input click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I know it is kind of silly/minor mistake. but i could not able to find it.

I wrote same code as mentioned here http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default but still nothing.

Code:

```
<input type="text" id="hasDatepicker" class="fromDate large hasDatepicker" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off">
```

JS :

```
$(".hasDatepicker").datepicker();
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mkcb5b0e/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is `hasDatepicker` is an internal class used by the jQuery UI datepicker to determine whether datepicker widget is already initialized for the selected element, if so then it doesn't do anything.

So in your case since your `input` already has the class the `.datepicker()` call doesn't do anything assuming that the widget is already initialized.

```js
$(".hasDatepicker2").datepicker();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="hasDatepicker" class="fromDate large hasDatepicker2" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: So the culprit was class `hasDatePicker`

Comment: I take my hat off to you sir! I was also setting the class name to hasDatepicker - didn't know it was an indicator whether the datepicker() class thought it was initialized! Regarding this answer, wouldn't the question require an ID initialize? i.e. $("#hasDatepicker").datepicker();

Comment: You saved me from a hour of debugging mate

Answer (score 2):

Correct code-

HTML Code -  (remove hasDatepicker from class)

```
<input type="text" id="hasDatepicker" class="fromDate large" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off">
```

jQuery Code-  (give #hasDatepicker as selector)

```
$("#hasDatepicker").datepicker();
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/m3adjs1r/

Answer (score 1):

You are using Id so you have to call like `$("#hasDatepicker").datepicker();`
Dot is used for classes. # is used for id's. Also you need to load jquery UI script. Datepicker is a UI element. Also it is not good to give id & class the same name.

Full working code from jquery

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**choice 1** : Change your class Name "hasDatepicker"  to another name.

**choice 2** : Remove class Name "hasDatepicker" and select by id.

```
$("#hasDatepicker").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an class in your JS try to make it and ID:

```
$("#hasDatepicker").datepicker();
```